# How can I use Javascript to simplify this code?

Tags: javascript

I started to learn Javascript and I'm building some sites to improve my skills. But here I would like to share with you a code that I couldn't simplify. As you will realize, I'm getting the ID of some DIVS to then add a event that go to differents categories. But, I can't find the way to make it easier without use all this code.

````
let entradas = document.getElementById("entradas");
entradas.addEventListener("click",irUrl1);
function irUrl1 () {
    window.location = "https://jikan.es/menu/entradas"
}


let veggie = document.getElementById("veggie");
veggie.addEventListener("click",irUrl2);
function irUrl2 () {
    window.location = "https://jikan.es/menu/veggie"
}


let rollsEspeciales = document.getElementById("rolls-especiales");
rollsEspeciales.addEventListener("click",irUrl3);
function irUrl3 () {
    window.location = "https://jikan.es/menu/especiales"
}


let pokeBowls = document.getElementById("poke-bowls");pokeBowls.addEventListener("click",irUrl4);
function irUrl4 () {
    window.location = "https://jikan.es/menu/poke-bowls"
}


let sashimi = document.getElementById("sashimi-niguiris");
sashimi.addEventListener("click",irUrl5);
function irUrl5 () {
    window.location = "https://jikan.es/menu/sashimi-niguiris"
}


let combinados = document.getElementById("combinados");
combinados.addEventListener("click",irUrl6);
function irUrl6 () {
    window.location = "https://jikan.es/menu/combinados"
}


let rollsClasic = document.getElementById("rolls-clasicos");
rollsClasic.addEventListener("click",irUrl7);
function irUrl7 () {
    window.location = "https://jikan.es/menu/rolls-clasicos"
}



let rollsSignature = document.getElementById("rolls-signature");
rollsSignature.addEventListener("click",irUrl8);
function irUrl8 () {
    window.location = "https://jikan.es/menu/rolls-signature"
}



let promociones = document.getElementById("promociones");
promociones.addEventListener("click",irUrl9);
function irUrl9 () {
    window.location = "https://jikan.es/menu/promociones"
}


    

</script>```
````

Comment: If all you're doing is redirecting the user, why not use anchor tags instead?

Comment: Using libraries like jQuery can shorten the code, or you can combine the lines.

Comment: It isn't a button, I want that the user click on an entire DIV and then redirect to other link. When I create a div with Elementor, I can't add a link to a DIV, the only way that I found to do this was with this code, that actually works to achieve my goal, but I would like to simplify using loops or for, I tried, but I wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: semantically if an element takes you to another webpage, that element should be an anchor tag.  You can style the anchor tag however you wish

Comment: Could you me write an example ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything in one line:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#entradas,#veggie,#rolls-especiales,#poke-bowls,#sashimi-niguiris,#combinados,#rolls-clasico,#rolls-signature,#promociones").forEach(el=>el.addEventListener("click",()=>window.location = "https://jikan.es/menu/"+el.id.replace("rolls-especiales","especiales")));
```

There seems to be one exception to the rule which I have taken care of with the `replace()` function: the id `#rolls-especiales` needs to be redirected to `especiales` (without "rolls-").

However, the best solution would still be to simply use `<a href="...">` tags of some kind in the html markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the codes from:

```
let entradas = document.getElementById("entradas");
entradas.addEventListener("click",irUrl1);
function irUrl1 () {
    window.location = "https://jikan.es/menu/entradas"
}
```

to:

```
document.getElementById("entradas").addEventListener("click", function() {
    window.location = "https://jikan.es/menu/entradas";
});
```

or you can use jQuery:

```
$('#entradas').click(function() {
    window.location = "https://jikan.es/menu/entradas";
});
```

Comment: I'm repeating the same process for the other "Categories" when for example I write the code to redirect to the url, how could I use just one function to all?. I'm writing irUrl1 then irUrl2, etc... same when I add "the event"

Answer (score 0):

```
['entradas', 'veggie'].forEach(id => {
  document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.location = `https://jikan.es/menu/${id}`
  })
})
```

this should reduce your repetition, but still I think the correct way to code would be to use anchor tags styled like your divs e.g.

```
<a style="whatever styles your div has" href="..." />
```